# PHP Mail make link to PDF save

Tags: php, pdf

I create a PDF via PHP and then save it onto my server.  I then do something like this using PHPMailer

```
$mail->Body    = 'Please download the PDF from ' . $downloadPDF;
```

When you click on the link in the email, the PDF currently opens up in the browser.  Is there any way to force a download of the PDF file, rather than use the browser?

Thanks

Comment: This is the question of the http headers you send when delivering the file _and_ of the client side configuration (which you cannot know or change from the server side).

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htaccess` file on your server. Put that file in your document root.

And than put below code in your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Comment: Why would one want to do that? With the header resulting from such a setup you have lost even the last bit of control. Now it is completely up to the clients fallback configuration what happens. Why not send the correct mime type and disposition?

Comment: @arkascha: Yeah you are right. Its depend on client configuration but If there is only need to download PDF file than normally we can do force download pdf like this way.